# How to detect what our computers are sending to outside

Tags: internet

I came around and saw

https://github.com/pooler/electrum-ltc/issues/176

Turns out they did some tests and found out

[image]

From that software, he knows that somebody is sending message to 111.90.149.131

Which is the hacker's server.

What software is that? I want to check potential keyloggers in my computer and want to know too.

Answer (score 3):

The software in the picture is called "Wireshark" its official website is: https://www.wireshark.org/ and it is available for Linux / Mac and Windows.
It allows you to capture all packets leaving a certain network interface. They can then be viewed inside the software including the headers and the payload of an packet.